# X-SERVERSOCKET: REUSE Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, httpwebrequest, fiddler

my code

```
webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://----------.com") as HttpWebRequest;
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                webRequest.CookieContainer = this.ReadCookies();
                webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                //webRequest.Proxy = null;
                webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8888");
                webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                webRequest.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://agent.sriwijayaair.co.id");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,es;q=0.2");
                webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36";
                webRequest.Referer = "https://--------.com";
                webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                webRequest.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 15, 200);
                webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                webRequest.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
                webRequest.ServicePoint.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(webRequest.ServicePoint, (byte)0, null);

                StreamWriter newStream1 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
                newStream1.Write(data);
                newStream1.Close();
```

i got fiddler properties **X-SERVERSOCKET: REUSE ServerPipe#174**

but when i access direct to site (not from my asp.net), **fiddler show X-SERVERSOCKET: REUSE ServerPipe#17 *NEW***

what mean "*NEW*" on direct site? how can be different when i use my asp.net application and to direct the site ?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler's `X-ServerSocket` flag simply tracks whether or not the request reused an existing server connection. Generally speaking, you don't need to care about this flag.

`Reuse ServerPipe #174` means that the connection originally used for Session #174 was used for this response. In contrast, `Reuse ServerPipe#17*NEW` means that Fiddler first attempted to reuse the connection established for Session #17, but that reuse failed (typically meaning that the server had closed the connection before it could be reused) and thus Fiddler subsequently created a new connection to the server.